# Math columns in tabularray

Tags: tables, tabularray

The package [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) seems like a good start, but the documentation is really sparse. Is there a way to add math columns? Like `X[$]` in [tabu](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) or `\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}`in [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array).

Comment: What about something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={l>{$}c<{$}}}
    text & \alpha 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}`?

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! Post it as an answer and I will mark it as the solution. Bonus points if you can define a new column type like the `newcolumntype`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={l>{$}c<{$}}}
    text & \alpha 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={lC}}
    text & \alpha 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Since version 2021P, [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package has `$` and `$$` options for cells/rows/columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={lQ[c,$]Q[r,$$]},hlines}
  text & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{4} \\
  text & \frac{5}{6} & -\frac{7}{8}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]