# Table text overlapping

Tags: tables, graphics, formatting, width, overlap

I am trying to make a table with the following code, but the first column second row contents are overlapping with the first column third row. This does not happen for the entire row. I tried to use scriptsize, small, change the length between rows by defining "extra" as some posts have suggested, but none seem to work. What am I missing here? I get the output as shown below, for the problem - column.

```
 \newlength{\extra}
  \setlength{\extra}{.8ex}

 \begin{table}[]
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{67FD9A} 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Mechanical\\ System\end{tabular}}                             
& \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Current limit\\          (A)\end{tabular}} & 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Power\\ Input (W)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular} 
[c]{@{}l@{}}Power\\ Output (W)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Efficiency\\    
(\%)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
                                                                                             & 
 133                                                                           & 31807                                                              
& 28992                                                               & 91.15                                                                 
\\ \cline{2-5} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\scriptsize With \\ \scriptsize 
Rotational\\ \scriptsize Damper\end{tabular}}}   & 200                                                                           
& 37319                                                              & 34067                                                               
& 91.285                                                                \\  \hline
                                                                                             & 
133                                                                           & 18159                                                              
& 16005                                                               & 88.14                                                                 
\\ [\extra] \cline{2-5} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Without\\ Rotational\\ 
Damper\end{tabular}}} & 200                                                                           
& 18603                                                              & 16096                                                               
& 86.52                                                                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Overlap]

Comment: Do you know how to use `\multirow`?

Comment: @Werner I tried to! But it's not quite working out :(

Comment: please always provide a small but complete test document not a fragment where we have to guess the required packages to complete a test document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I apologize, I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about a `tabularray` based approach?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{67FD9A} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={l S[table-format=3] S[table-format=5] S[table-format=5] S[table-format=3.2]}, 
             hlines, vlines, 
             row{1}={mygreen, font=\bfseries\small, halign=c}, 
             vspan=even}
{Mechanical\\ System}                            
& {{{{Current limit\\ (A)}}}} 
& {{{{Power Input\\ (W)}}}}
& {{{Power Output\\ (W)}}} 
& {{{Efficiency \\(\%)}}}
\\ 
{\SetCell[r=2]{}With\\ Rotational\\ Damper}    & 133 & 31807 & 28992 & 91.15  \\
                                               & 200 & 37319 & 34067 & 91.285 \\  
{\SetCell[r=2]{}Without\\ Rotational\\ Damper} & 133 & 18159 & 16005 & 88.14  \\ 
                                               & 200 & 18603 & 16096 & 86.52  \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I did not know how to use this at all.

Comment: I am trying to label and caption this table I added following your answer in this link - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599784/math-columns-in-tabularray, but I'm not getting it

Comment: @SM32, be more specific, what you try (the best with new question where you show us with MWE, what is your problem). Caption you can add as at any other tables: insert caption, table label and table code in the float `table` environment.

Answer (score 7):

Too long for a comment to @leandriss answer.

More in spirit of the `tabularray` package syntax, the table's code is:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{67FD9A}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c, wd=5em] Q[c, si={table-format=3}] 
                              *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=5}]} 
                                   Q[c, si={table-format=2.3}]
                     },
             hlines, vlines,
             row{1}={bg=mygreen, font=\bfseries\small},
             vspan=even}
Mechanical System
    & {{{Current limit\\ (A)}}}
        & {{{Power Input\\ (W)}}}
            & {{{Power Output\\ (W)}}}
                & {{{Efficiency \\ (\%)}}}  \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l} With Rotational Damper     & 133 & 31807 & 28992 & 91.15  \\
                                            & 200 & 37319 & 34067 & 91.285 \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l} Without Rotational Damper  & 133 & 18159 & 16005 & 88.14  \\
                                            & 200 & 18603 & 16096 & 86.52  \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**
In contrary to other tables packages the `tabularray` package handle `multirow` cells such that they consider the number of spanned adjacent rows and not number of text lines in those rows. Consequently, contents never spill out of cell rather automatically increase the height of the last spanned row or when used with the option `vspan=even`, heights of all spanned rows are evenly increased.

More features of this relatively new (and still fast developing package) as well as its syntax, which quite differ from syntax of other table packages are described in the package documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @SM32, the policy of this site is that thankfulness for answer  is expressed by upvoting of answer. If you like both answers, you can award both of them (by clicking on up-triangle at top left side of answers. You may also accept one of them which to your opinion on the best way solve your problem.

Comment: @SM32, see added short explanation/advertising for `tabularray` package :-)

Comment: @Zarko Your presentation of code is very nice. Which editor do you use to write code?

Comment: @Imran, thank you very much for correcting spelling and languages errors! I use WinEdt editor, however text formatting in editor is done manually.

Comment: @Zarko That's a lot of manual formatting task! But the code is so good-looking and easy to read that it pays off the hard-working.

Comment: @Imran, for WinEdt exist "library" for prettify tables code but so far I didn't use it, so don't know how to use it and what is its result. It can be find on WinEdt home page (at least information, where is available).

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. Just installed it. Going to give it a try.